# What is the console command(s) to modify the lockpicking skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm hacking Skyrim skill levels through console commands by:

```
advanceskill [skill name] number
```

But when I type:

```
advanceskill lockpicking xxx
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: It's "lockpicking", not "lockpiking". Did you make the same typo in the console?

Comment: You can try your hand at "lockpiking" in nethack, but it's likely to damage the weapon.

Comment: Use `AdvSkill` instead.

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29/Skills

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `advanceskill`, it's `AdvSkill`

See here: [Skyrim Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29/Skills)

Note that `advskill lockpicking 1` will raise both your lockpicking skill and player level, while `player.setav skill level` will only raise the skill level without leveling up your player character.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to AdvSkill which was mentioned in the answer of Asunez, there also is `incPCS`. This is fairly safe since you only modify the skill itself and you can't modify something "accidentally".

```
incPCS lockpicking
```

This will increase your lockpicking skill by 1. The difference to AdvSkill is, that it doesn't matter how much experience is missing. It will simply fill up the bar. So you enter this once and then you simply spam it over and over again. Or you can copy it into a .bat file and execute it ingame via console. This is - in my opinion - the easiest way to gain fast skill levels if you really want to use the console for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you're searching is: `player.advskill lockpicking` followed by the skill level you wish to achieve.
If you only want to level up the skill without the character leveling up i can't help you. 
After you leveld up your skill and want your character to be an specific level you could use the `player.setlevel x` command to set a destined level.

Regards Lumisch